# Fatal error on Mink WebAssert.textPageContains when assertion fails

Tags: selenium, behat, mink

I'm using `Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver`. This is the `@Then` function for one of my features:

```php
/**
 * @Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iShouldSee($result)
{
    $verification = new WebAssert($this->session);
    try
    {
        $verification->pageTextContains($result);
    }
    catch(ResponseTextException $e)
    {
        printf("something went wrong");
    }
}
```

If I write a scenario where the assertion should pass, I have no problem: it runs properly and creates the output file in junit format that I will pass to Jenkins later.

But if I change the scenario so it should fail, the execution is interrupted after the failed assertion text and I get this message:

```
Then I should see "my text"        # MyCompany\MyBDDBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext::iShouldSee()
The text "my text" was not found anywhere in the text of the current page.

PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function text() on a non-object in C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.15-0\frameworks\symfony\vendor\behat\mink-selenium2-driver\src\Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver.php on line 464

Fatal error: Call to a member function text() on a non-object in C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.15-0\frameworks\symfony\vendor\behat\mink-selenium2-driver\src\Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver.php on line 464
```

I've been looking the Selenium2Driver.php file and line 464 is inside function `getText($xpath)` that I just don't use.

And finally, having the test been interrupted, the junit file that is created as an output only contains the XML header, although there were many passed scenarios.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Why is the test working when the assertion passes but it crashes when it fails?

Comment: Could you please define what "if I change the scenario so it should fail" means? You change the code or you change the expected result that should definitely fail upon assert?
 
Here you can see that you actually indirectly use that getText() method http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/Behat/Mink/source-class-Behat.Mink.WebAssert.html#148-163

Comment: Thanks Eduard. I asked this question almost two and a half years ago and I don't remember the exact details. I think I just changed the expected result to something not present on the page. Anyway, if getText() throws an exception different from ResponseTextException, then pageTextContains() should be aware of that.